# Having Trouble Centering a Div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have my "boxes" div centered on my page so that everything inside of that div acts as it is acting now but centered on my page instead of pushed to the left.

Unfortunately, the way I visioned my CSS isn't the way it turned out.

If someone wouldn't mind looking over my jsbin http://jsbin.com/ijifah/1 I'd appreciate it.

The end-goal is to have the boxes centered on the page.

- Initially I thought I would put all three boxes in a div.
- After, I would make the boxes.
- Lastly, I would center the div "boxes" that contains all three of my boxes. Unfortunately this isn't working.

I have been using the

```
 {display:block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  }
```

To center a lot of the objects in my CSS.

CSS:

```
.boxes  {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
.basecamp {
    width: 160px;
    height: 217px;
    border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    font-family: Lucida Grande;
    background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF,#F0F0F0);
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

.logos {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.basecamp a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #3366A7;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Lucida Grande;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.logo-headers {
    color:#CC0000;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Lucida Grande;
}

  .logo-p {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
font-family: Lucida Grande;
font-size: 14px;
margin-top: -10px;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="basecamp">
        <img src="images/logo-bc.png" alt="logo" class="logos">
        <a href="#">Basecamp</a>
        <h5 class="logo-headers">Manage Projects</h5>
        <p class="logo-p">Used by millions for project management.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="basecamp">
        <img src="images/logo-bc.png" alt="logo" class="logos">
        <a href="#">Basecamp</a>
        <h5 class="logo-headers">Manage Projects</h5>
        <p class="logo-p">Used by millions for project management.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="basecamp">
        <img src="images/logo-bc.png" alt="logo" class="logos">
        <a href="#">Basecamp</a>
        <h5 class="logo-headers">Manage Projects</h5>
        <p class="logo-p">Used by millions for project management.</p>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
```

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this good for you: http://jsbin.com/upuwil/1  ? 
These two new css properties do the trick:

```
.boxes  {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'll try making a link on jsfiddle, not sure why that isn't working

Comment: @Codey did you check the link in my answer?

Comment: Thanks for the input.  This is working.  I'm a little confused why,haha but I am guessing it has something to do with text being an inline element instead of a block. Maybe? haha.

Comment: @Codey exactly , "inline" element can be centered like this relatively  to its parent

Answer (score 0):

To center a div in CSS I use:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

try that

Answer (score 0):

```
.boxes  {
   position: relative;
   display:inline-block;
}
<center>
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="basecamp">
        <img src="images/logo-bc.png" alt="logo" class="logos">
        <a href="#">Basecamp</a>
        <h5 class="logo-headers">Manage Projects</h5>
        <p class="logo-p">Used by millions for project management.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="basecamp">
        <img src="images/logo-bc.png" alt="logo" class="logos">
        <a href="#">Basecamp</a>
        <h5 class="logo-headers">Manage Projects</h5>
        <p class="logo-p">Used by millions for project management.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="basecamp">
        <img src="images/logo-bc.png" alt="logo" class="logos">
        <a href="#">Basecamp</a>
        <h5 class="logo-headers">Manage Projects</h5>
        <p class="logo-p">Used by millions for project management.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
```